# Looping through the size of a getter?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, getter-setter

I have this method here:

```
public void returnCoreUnitsForProgram( int index )
{   
    if ( ProgramArray.get(index).getProgramMajor().equals("Software Technology") )
    {        
     /*for(int i = 0; i< size of getUnitType.equals("Core"); i++)*/                        
       for(int i = 0; i< UnitArray.size(); i++)
       {
            System.out.println( UnitArray.get(i).getUnitName() );
       }                
    }                
}
```

As stated in the comment line I need to loop through the **size of the getter method** `getUnitType()`.

The purpose is to narrow down the displayed units to those with only the Unit Type "Core".

I tried:

```
i < UnitArray.get(i).getUnitType().equals("Core")
```

and

```
UnitArray.get(i).getUnitType().equals("Core").size()
```

and of course it failed - miserably.

I'm stuck at this part here. Any pointers guys?

Comment: what does "loop through the size of the getter method" mean?

Comment: can you ad some more code here. what you have written is not clear

Comment: won't `getUnitType.equals("Core").size()` work? 
what is return type of getUnitType.equals?

Comment: I apologize but the code is extremely lengthy so I thought of reducing it to this short since it's only the loop that has issue. What I meant by _"loop through the size of the getter method"_ is that I'm trying to set the condition so that the loop will not loop through the entire UnitArray - but just the specific getter that returns unit type called "Core". I hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will work for you

```
public void returnCoreUnitsForProgram( int index )
{   
    if (ProgramArray.get(index).getProgramMajor().equals("Software Technology"))
    {                      
       for(int i = 0; i< UnitArray.size(); i++)
       {
           if (UnitArray.get(i).getUnitType().equals("Core"))
               System.out.println( UnitArray.get(i).getUnitName() );
       }                
    }                
}
```

equals() returns boolean value not an array/list so you were using it wrong way.

Comment: Ah I see so what I needed is another if...else inside that checks for "Core". Thanks!